# Reading a specific XML tag propertie/s using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have my configuration file as follows:

```
<application>
  <sites>
    <site name="Default Web Site" id="100">
      <application path="/" applicationPool="Default Web Site">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\inetpub\folder1" />
      </application>
    </site>
    <site name="Default Web Site2" id="200">
      <application path="/" applicationPool="Default Web Site">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\inetpub\folder2" />
      </application>
    </site>
  </sites>
</application>
```

I need to go to each web site and get its physical path.  I have done following-

```
string filepath = @"C:\Users\Host.config";
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(fs);
if (File.Exists(filepath))
{
  do
  {
    switch (rdrXml.NodeType)
    {
      //case XmlNodeType.Element:
      //    TextBox1.Text = rdrXml.Name;
      //    break;

      case XmlNodeType.Element:
      if (rdrXml.Name== "site")
      {  
        string webname= rdrXml["name"].ToString();
        TextBox2.Text = webname;
        if (rdrXml.Name == "virtualDirectory") 
        {
          TextBox1.Text = rdrXml["physicalPath"].ToString();
        }
      }
      break;
    }
  } while (rdrXml.Read());
} // file exists check
```

But I am not able to get to the Default Web Site's PhysicalPath.  It is either- either I get the path or the name of the site and not both.  Is there a way to identify both ?

Comment: Don't nest those if statements

Comment: `need to go to each web site and get its physical path` First you need a valid xml

Comment: how do you code with that kind of indentation?

Answer (score 0):

I used  Microsoft.Web.Administration for this and was able to get what I want.